# What is wrong with this binary search? IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to write the binary search algorithm, But [Geeks for Geeks practice problem Binary Search](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/binary-search/1#) yields following error:

```
Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 

  Index 222 out of bounds for length 5

    at Solution.binarysearch(GFG.java:44)
    at GFG.main(GFG.java:22)
```

What I've written so far is,

```
class Solution {
    int binarysearch(int arr[], int n, int k){
        
        if (arr == null) return -1;
        
        int begin = 0;
        int end = k;

            for (; begin < end;)
            {
                int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
                if (arr[mid] == n) return mid;
                if (arr[mid] > n)
                {
                    // in left part
                    begin = begin;  // for debug
                    end = mid; 
                }
                else
                {
                    // in right part
                    begin = mid + 1;
                    end = end; // for debug
                }
            }

            return -1;
    }
}
```

Geeks for Geeks problem statement&example:

> Given a sorted array of size N and an integer K, find the position at
> which K is present in the array using binary search.
>
> **Example 1**:
>
> **Input**: N = 5  arr[] = {1 2 3 4 5}  K = 4
> **Output**: 3
> **Explanation**: 4 appears at index 3.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int end = k;` to `int end = n-1;`

`k` is the number you have to find, `n` is the array size

Comment: why not just with n instead of n-1 ?

Comment: Because, it is 0-based

Comment: So what????????

Comment: If array size is 3 then the indices are 0, 1, 2 (which is 3-1 = 2)

Comment: so no problem??

Comment: no problem!!!!!

Comment: These conversations are so funny and should be archieved on Wikipedia. Thanks for the laugh.